# Team Explorer Everywhere command line can't checkin

Tags: team-explorer-everywhere

When I try to do a checkin command I get an error saying `No changes were matched by any arguments`, but the file has in fact been changed! The culprit seems to be that TEE didn't automatically checkout the file upon edit, even though MSDN seems to suggest that it should have ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yft8zkw.aspx)).

OK big deal, so I tried to checkout the file instead knowing I'd have to make the changes again. But this time I'm getting a new error saying:

```
An error occurred: TF400032: The operation could not be completed because the workspace 
WORKSPACE_NAME is a local workspace.
```

Things get more bizarre when I try to do other things, like a simple add; it gives the same error! It seems that the only thing I could get working was using `tf get` to update everything to the latest version.

I'm at a loss to what's causing this after several attempts:
(right now I'm not able to push any changes to the server)

1. Modified file using vim. `tf status` doesn't report changes
2. Tried `tf checkin file.m` and `tf checkin file.m -force`, both of which reported no changes
3. Tried `tf get file.m`, but it reports that the file is up to date. Tried `tf get file.m -force` and this time it properly replaced the file with the server version
4. Tried `tf checkout file.m`, but it reports the error message about the local workspace
5. Tried `tf add file.m`, but it reports the same error message about the local workspace

Here's some details on my setup:

- OS: Red Hat Enterprise Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
- TEE version: TEE-CLC-12.0.2
- `TF_AUTO_SAVE_CREDENTIALS` is set in bash
- Workspace was set up with:

  ```
  tf workspace -new "WORKSPACE_NAME" -collection:https://example.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection
  tf workfold -map "$/example_folder" -workspace:"WORKSPACE_NAME" "~/example_folder/"
  ```

Comment: I  have encountered the same question.My environment is Mac OS X 10.10,Intellij 14.1 connect to TFS 2014

Comment: `tf checkout` only works for server workspaces -- where you have to explicitly check things out to pick up that they are changed -- (local workspaces don't have checkout). -- Are you sure the modified files are getting their archive attribute unset when you edit them?

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 That explains the workspace errors, but I'm still unable to do any checkins as the tf client complains that no changes have occurred. Not quite sure what you meant by the archive attribute; I thought that was a Windows thing?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it is relevant in your case, but for me that was the issue:

If you are connected to a cluster, with multiple computers/servers,
the workspace is created for the specific server you were logged in to (although the storage is probably shared).

This results in the workspace having a computer name that mismatches the computer name from which you'd might later check in your file.

The only solution I found so far is to connect to the specific node which I was running the creation of the workspace and work from that node. (or to upload the edited file using the web interface).
Same issue will rise if you work locally, but changed your computer name or any related configuration (domain for example).

Hope it helps...